# How do I add data to SQLite db based on data as a condition?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have an app which receives data from a device. The device stores some data in its internal memory and it stores the data and time stamp as well. When this device connects back to the app, I want the data to be synced. How do I add data to the SQLite database using "date-time" as a condition for adding?
My code to add is :

```
 public void enterValues(int idno,int type,float value, String currenttime){
    // Code to insert values into the dB
    try {

        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put("work_id",idno);
        cv.put("type",type);
        cv.put("value",value);
        cv.put("currenttime", currenttime);


    db.insert(table, null, cv);
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
     ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is my code to add data to db when my device is CONNECTED to the app. Now when its NOT CONNECTED, the device itself stores date-time as well. So how do I selectively add this in the right position in the database? How do I check for this condition and then add the value to the appropriate position in the database?

Comment: Is work_id a unique key? Or is there a unique key somewhere in the device data?

Comment: work_id is a unique key. Every workout "session" has a work_id generated. Howveer, this is generated in the app and not device.